# When something sounds too good to be true, it is or isn't?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions

I'm having a hard time understanding why the phrase is

> when something sounds too good to be true, it **is**

and not

> when something sounds too good to be true, it **isn't**

Because "when something sounds too good be true," it "is ***not*** true", right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searcheg Google Ngrams. The vast majority of returns ended with "*it is."* Which is strange to me, as I used the phrase here (on EL&U) with *it isn't*.

In both cases, the phrase works, because the last phrase can be the correct answer to two different parts of the prior phrase in the saying.

> When something sounds too good to be true, it is (too good to be true.)
>
> When something sounds too good to be true, it isn't (true.)

When something really is *too good to be true*, people say *"I thought it was..." or "It seemed"* too good to be true, because obviously if it was true, it only *appeared* to be too good to be true.

Comment: In a sentence like this, it doesn't hurt to use a little repetition and/or an adverb.  `When something sounds too good to be true, it is too good to be true`, or just... `,it usually is.`

Answer (score 0):

when something sounds too good to be true, it is (too good to be true).